# Can you play a radio stream with google actions?

Tags: action, actions-on-google, google-home

Is there a way to output a radiostream on devices that use googles assistant? Basically I need to develop an action that is streaming audio constantly just like any other already built in radio service. But here the action would have to be activated manually and then the device would start to play radio.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No the actions on Google platform doesn't support streaming audio.